# Sharepoint 2010 NintexWokflow won't save

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, nintex-workflow

I have a workflow which is working in the intranet, I have edit the workflow with nintex workflow on Friday and I was able to save it properly until today were I tried to edit and save the workflow but its giving me an error below:

Server was unable to process request ---> The filehttp://inet/solutions/support/Nintexworkflows/Service Status V2/Service Status V2.xoml.wfconfig.xml is checked out for editing by me

I don't know how to check in that file again and I don't know were the file is located
someone with the solution to help me on how to do this or resolve this error

I am using Nintex Workflows in SharePoint 2010 seeing that I can't create new tags

Answer (score 1):

Solution I found

- Open the support site via SharePoint 2010
- Navigate to file you want
- Check in any files that are checked out

The you can continue editing you workflow

Answer (score 1):

1. Sharepoint has a hidden library 'NintexWorkflows' URL: "[Web
   Application Name]/[Site Collection Name]/[Site
   Name]/NintexWorkflows"
2. All the workflow folders are contained in this library
3. Browse to your workflow and check-in the xoml file

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of fixes.
I restart WM Ware, and it fix the problem.